# Objectify transaction vs. regular load then save

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I need only confirmation that I get this right. 
If, for example I have an Entity `X` with a field `x`, and when a request is sent I want to do `X.x++`. If I use just `X = ofy().load().type(X.class).id(xId).get()` then I do some calculations and afterwards I do `X.x++` and the I save it. If during the calculations another request is posted, I'll get an unwanted behavior. And instead if I'll do this all in a transaction, the second request won't have access to `X` until I finish.

Is it so?

Sorry if the question is a bit nooby.

Thanks, 
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you got it right but when using transaction remember the first that completes wins and the rest fail. Look also at @Peter Knego's answer for how they work.

But don't worry about the second request if it fails to read. 
You have like 2 options:

1. Force a retries
2. Use eventual consistency in your transactions

As far as the retries are concerned:

> Your transaction function can be called multiple times safely without
>   undesirable side effects. If this is not possible, you can set
>   retries=0, but know that the transaction will fail on the first
>   incident of contention

Example:

```
@db.transactional(retries=10)
```

As far as eventual consistency is concerned:

> You can opt out of this protection by specifying a read policy that
>   requests eventual consistency. With an eventually consistent read of
>   an entity, your app gets the current known state of the entity being
>   read, regardless of whether there are still committed changes to be
>   applied. With an eventually consistent ancestor query, the indexes
>   used for the query are consistent with the time the indexes are read
>   from disk. In other words, an eventual consistency read policy causes
>   gets and queries to behave as if they are not a part of the current
>   transaction. This may be faster in some cases, since the operations do
>   not have to wait for committed changes to be written before returning
>   a result.

Example:

```
@db.transactional()
def test():
    game_version = db.get(
        db.Key.from_path('GameVersion', 1),
        read_policy=db.EVENTUAL_CONSISTENCY)
```

Answer (score 2):

No, GAE transaction do not do locking, they use [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). You will have access to `X` all the time, but when you try to save it in the second transactions it will fail with `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: OK, in my case when I want to perform `X.x++`, after receiving a request I should do it in a transaction, for the case two request will come almost simultaneously?